# How can I organize info in my résumé in a better manner?

Tags: critique, resume

I'm an engineering undergrad and in a typical biodata format, my biodata easily runs into two pages.

I have been trying to make a one-page biodata but looks too congested to me (and a lot of other people).

[image: My attempt at a one page thing]

How can I better organize the stuff?
I appreciate your answers. Thank you ^^

Comment: My immediate reaction is to the typography. I can't figure out the hierarchy of type faces and type styles. It appears random. I'd start with rethinking that.

Comment: "Typical biodata" -- I've never heard this biodata term before. Is this just what people in India call a résumé? Are all of these sections standard for employers in India?

Comment: As @DA01 mentions, the typography is confusing. That is the first major issue. I would suggest revising that and updating your question, you want your resume to be clear and concise. Like  a website the most important thing is to clearly communicate information. Best of luck :)

Comment: @Ryan Erm, technically, biodata is a term graduates with little to no experience tend to use.

Comment: The typography and alignments are all over the place. Cut down to one font family, and when that looks decent, you can _think_ about adding another, but not before. Pay attention to the _sizes_. I am not sure, but form here it seems "interests" are even bigger than "Activities and ...". Also, a major cleanup in line-hights. Seems to me you have paragraph shifts that sometimes "belongs" to the font _above_ the space, and sometimes a paragraph shift that belongs to the font _below_. I suggest you do your best to do as @Ryan suggests, clean up fonts, and come back to us with that, to elegantify.

Comment: Oh, and _loose all that small-caps_!

Comment: There was so much going on I didnt even notice the small caps. Yes, get rid of that too as @RandomO'Reilly said

Answer (score 7):

There's a lot going on here but see if I can help you out.

First is alignment which has a lot going on.

The outer most area is different width on all 4 sides. This should really either be 1 width, or at most 2 widths (sides & top/bottom):

[image]

Then internally, nothing quite lines up correctly. This makes it difficult for a reader to follow. See in this close up how the letters aren't straight down:

[image]

Then there's all sorts of variations make it very difficult to follow. Here in red I tried to note it as best I could. Basically you've got completely different formats, and even fonts on here. All of them should follow the same format. If anything isn't clear in my notes let me know:

[image]

Then we've got more alignment issues over here:

[image]

The alignment is the biggest thing. Get everything in a format that fits. Then you can look at the typography. I'd also suggest ditching the word RESUME at the top. And the icons by your contact information. There's no reason for any of it and it takes up a huge chunk of paper.

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: I'd also put 'awards & special mentions' on one line and leave some white space between your columns.